# Rename one file with the first line of the file's contents (not batch)

Tags: bash, terminal, mv

I've searched a ton and found this answer for batch processing, but I'm looking for a simple answer that I can hopefully just enter on the command line, for changing the name of 1 file and replacing the name with the contents of the file's first line.

For file `foo.txt`
With the first line of the file's contents: `123`
Rename `foo.txt` as `123.txt`

Much thanks!

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 5):

```
mv fileName $(head -1 fileName).txt
```

`head -1 fileName` will retrieve the first line of a file, placing it inside of `$()` allows that code to execute and the result (the first line of the file) will become the second parameter of the `mv` command.

In your example, you are looking at:

```
mv foo.txt $(head -1 foo.txt).txt
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me:    mv foo.txt $(head -1 foo.txt).txt

Comment: fileName should be replaced with the name of your file. Does `foo.txt` exist already?

Comment: @Cath glad to hear it! feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: Notice that `head -1` is considered obsolete and only supported for backwards compatibility; new scripts should use `head -n 1` instead.